# TypeError: req.session.destroy is not a function - Express.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, session

I've made my webapp using React.js and Express.js as a web-server. React is connected to Express with this (for now) in package.json:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"
```

and in my Express server I've used this to handle sessions:

```
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
```

and this:

```
app.use(cookieSession({
 name: 'parse-session',
 secret: "SECRET_SIGNING_KEY",
 maxAge: 15724800000
}));
```

so when I use login to my API it works ok and this is the code to check if currentUser exist:

```
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

if(req.session.token){    

    console.log(req.session.token);
    request({

      uri:'http://myserver.herokuapp.com/parse/users/me',
      headers: {
        'X-Parse-Application-Id': 'my-app-id',
        'X-Parse-Session-Token': req.session.token
      },
      json:true    

    }).then((userData) => {

       if(userData){    

          resolve(userData);

       }

    }).catch((error) => {

        reject(error);
    });
  }
```

and it works without problem, with this call in React:

```
   fetch('/user',{credentials:'include'})
    .then((response)=>{
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((body)=>{
        if(body.user){
            this.setState({logIn:true});
        }

    }).catch((error)=>{
           console.log('My error:',error);

    });
```

The problem is when I try to logout: I do this on React:

```
 axios.post('/logout').then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);

 }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
 });
```

and this is logout on Express:

```
app.post('/logout',(req,res)=>{


if(req.session){

   req.session.destroy((error)=>{
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
   });
}
});
```

that gives to me this error message:

```
TypeError: req.session.destroy is not a function
```

why? I've seen that destroy() is a function. I've also tried to put :`req.session = null` but, when you call after the promise to check if session exist it currently alive.

Why? How could I use to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `delete req.session;` ? Also, if you see a session after any of the destruction methods, log the content, chances are it was actually destroyed and regenerated so you may have an empty session.

Comment: @ruedamanuel I've tried also to put req.session = null.. it is null, but if I try to redone the promise, it regenerates the session token

Comment: If the regenerated session token isn't authenticated in express then it should be ok, you are effectively logged out, I'm not sure of what your problem is in that case.

Comment: @ruedamanuel I don't know why it continue to regenerate, the only way to delete all is delete cookies in the browser...is it possible that token is also saved in react client app?

Comment: Have you tried invalidating the cookie in the response object? https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.clearCookie

Comment: @ruedamanuel Yes, I've tried it, but the problem still persist

Comment: Then try adding an `expires: new Date(0)` property, the library you're using sends a Set-Cookie header whenever there's a change in the cookie you're currently using, so if you add an expiration to a past date it should force the cookie to expire in the browser and therefore disappear

Comment: @ruedamanuel tried also this, but doesn't also works...I'm thinking to change authentication using jwt or see if there is another method of the lib cookie-session that delete the cookie...

Answer (score 20):

`req.session.destroy` is the call to use if you are using `express-session` npm module.  However, you are using `cookie-session` which in its current version does not define `req.session.destroy` resulting in the error that you are getting.

To destroy the session while using `cookie-session` , you just need to set it to null: `req.session = null`.  If you decide to use `express-session` instead, then `req.session.destroy` would work.

*References*:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-session
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. @ste9206 can you mark this as the answer?

Comment: @inorganik agreed

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cookieSession, then the correct way would be to route to /logout, and from there:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session) {
        req.session = null;
        res.redirect('/');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
});
```

If you're using express-session, `req.session.destroy` would work instead.